# Excel VBA to lock the clipboard during copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I need to move some OLEObjects from one worksheet to another.
Ideally I want to do it without using the clipboard, but I have been unable to do that so I try to copy paste.

When using the clipboard I try to lock it during the copy, paste with this:

```
Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub ClipLock()
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "OpenClipboard failed"
    ElseIf EmptyClipboard() = 0 Then
        MsgBox "EmptyClipboard failed"
    End If
End Sub

Sub ClipUnlock()
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Sub MoveShapes()

    ClipLock

    Dim oOLEObject As OLEObject
    For Each oOLEObject in ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects

        oOleObject.Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Paste

    Next oOleObject

    ClipUnlock

End Sub
```

The `ClipLock` is blocking the clibboard ok. I can't copy anything in any other program while it is running.
The problem is that the VBA Copy, Paste is also blocked.

I wonder if this is due to the way it is invoked.
Another program is starting Excel and using com automation to load an addin, and then running the Sub in the addin.

So maybe the hwnd in OpenClipboard needs to be specified...?
I tried `Application.hwnd` and `ActiveWindow.hwnd`, and the Win32 apis `GetActiveWindow` and `GetDesktopWindow`, but VBA was still blocked from the clipboard.

Am I on the right path with the hwnd being the issue?
How should hwnd be set for `OpenClipboard` if not using zero?
Is there a way to move them without resorting to the clipboard?